# Parent to vertex unwanted offset

Tags: animation, geometry, parent

Making an wraping dodecahedron animation. All the pentagon's movements are related with parent vertex.
It's ok on the final stage - all connects correct, but while the animation the pentagons are moving with unwanted offset one from each over: 
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by 'parent vertex'? Could you describe a bit more the way the parenting is done or upload your file here http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/?

Comment: OK, thnks, uploading the file. "vertex parenting" as described here" - https://docs.blender.org/manual/de/dev/editors/3dview/object/properties/relations/parents.html

Comment: OK... to me, parenting like that and using shape keys is far from the simple way to do that. Mainly because shape keys wont rotate but will linearly interpolate the positions. I suggest you use armature parenting having the bones rotating from 0 to 63.44° (check that!). Note also that this parenting can be made so that all pentagons are connected in one mesh with no doubles (the flat shape, I mean)

Comment: or... far better... simply use object parenting between pentagons!

Comment: but how can I rotate i OBJECT mode along the axe I need? Same for bones! I know how to rotate in edit mode...

Comment: Ctrl+Alt+Space can be used to define custom orientations axis https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/User:Rking/Doc:2.6/Manual/3D_interaction/Transform_Control/Transform_Orientations. From that, select a pentagon's edge and define this custom orientation from it (sorry wont have time to write an answer now...)

Comment: Note that it will work with the manipulator but not with R shortcut (a bug?)

Comment: FYI, after a little test: you will have calculation rounding so that parenting at object level wont work (similar to your first attempt even if smaller). So, I think using bones on one single mesh is better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer as already answered here  [Wrapping geometry object animation](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/74275/wrapping-geometry-object-animation/74282#74282)

If you start with a face setting like this, you can rotate 72° to obtain the other faces:

[image]

Now if you set the snapping like this:

[image]

And use an empty as active element, you can place the face next to the others as you need:

[image]

Finally you obtain this:

[image]

From that you'll need (I describe this quickly as this is not the direct subject):

- to join the bones,
- join the faces (and remove double)
- parent them with empty groups and assign the needed vertices to the corresponding groups manually

Now, as the bones are all along their local axis (along Y), you can rotate them all around X using 'individual origins':

[image]

So you can rotate them all around their local X axis, using <kbd>R</kbd><kbd>XX</kbd> (twice X for local axis):

[image]

Last step: the dodecahedron as an angle of arcTan(2) = 63.434949°. So we need 
to set a keyframe for this rotation value.

[image]

[image]