# (Scripting) Set edge as axis for object rotation

Tags: python, scripting

I am trying to write a script that does the exact same thing as can be found [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28829/set-edge-as-axis-for-surface-rotation?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa).

I have an object that I want to rotate around one of its own edges, as shown in the link, but can't figure out how to do it.

Like below, I want to rotate the selected object around the edge that is closest to the other object.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to bse. Could you please edit the first link, it points to the new question atm.

Comment: Oh ye, good catch! Should be fixed