# how to rotate along a row of edges

Tags: faces

I need to to rotate these faces inwards, towards the back of the guitar, along the line of selected edges at the back 
[image]

I cant seem to find a way to do this.
Thanks!

Comment: You can add custom orientations. Select an edge you want to rotate around, then on the 'N' (right panel), navigate to the 'transform orientations' sections and click on the + button. That will add a custom orientation you can select and use the same way as builtin orientation. From that in your situation, place and use the 3D cursor as pivot (on the edge) and rotate the faces.

Comment: Look at the right bottom part of the guitar body, the topology is much better there... To later help yourself also with texturing, have you tried to retopologize that part? the quad flow is not good...

Comment: [Related](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28829/set-edge-as-axis-for-surface-rotation)  Follow instructions in answer, edge select mode and select an edge on axis of revolution last. Your screenshot pivot point is in "median point" and transform in "global", need to change to "active element" and "normal" respectively.

Comment: thanks a lot, that has really helped! P.S m.ardito, I'm planning to just make the body one solid colour so the topology shoulden't matter. Tell me if i'm wrong