# Rotate group of objects over an edge

Tags: transforms, edges, 3d-printing

What I am trying to do is similar to what was asked here:  [Set edge as axis for surface rotation](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28829/set-edge-as-axis-for-surface-rotation)

I am hoping to use an object's edge for rotation, but instead of simply the one object rotating around that point, it'd be a bunch of stl's I've imported together:
[image]

[image]

What I'm hoping to do is duplicate everything in that tetrahedron object, rotate the duplicate along one edge like this:

[image]

to build a stack of them, like this:   which I would then print.  Any help?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to do it:

- Select the edge that you want as axis.
- Press *ctrl alt spacebar* to record this axis as one of your *Transform Orientation* axis. Keep this axis selected in the *Transform Orientation* dropdown menu.
- Put your 3D Cursor on the selected edge with a *shift S* > *Cursor To Selected*.
- Select *3D Cursor* in the *Pivot* dropdown menu
- Rotate your pyramid with *R Y Y* (or *X X*, depending of its name in the new Orientation Axis) and press the amount of degrees.
- To delete the orientation axis you don't need any more, in the 3D view press *N* to get the right menu and go to the *Transform Orientations* tab.

[image]

Comment: Worked amazing!  Thank you!  Only comment is I think it should be shift+s, not ctrl s.  At least on my computer ctrl s kept trying to save.  Maybe mine is set up wrong.

Comment: you're right   ;)